# JDBC Error (SQL syntax) Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

Im getting this unkown error when running this code:

```
String SELECT_getWhenValueChanged = "SELECT a.* FROM status AS a WHERE a.value <> (SELECT b.value FROM status AS b WHERE a.idCategory = ? AND b.idCategory = a.idCategory and a.timeStamp > b.timeStamp ORDER BY b.timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY timeStamp DESC";
    try {
        Survey surveyTemp = new Survey();
        surveyTemp = (Survey) getJdbcTemplate()
                .queryForObject(SELECT_getWhenValueChanged,
                        new Object[] { categoryId, categoryId },
                        new SurveyMapper());
        /*
         * SQL Question ask when the value has changed and get the value
         * that changed from and changed to, the first one is the current
         * value and the second is the value before it changed
         */

        if (!surveyTemp.getTimestamp().isEmpty()
                && !presentSurvey.getTimestamp().isEmpty()) {
            presentSurvey.setTimestamp(surveyTemp.getTimestamp());
        }
    } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return presentSurvey;
```

Anybody know what this means?

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT a.* FROM status AS a WHERE a.value <> (SELECT b.value FROM status AS b WHERE a.idCategory = ? AND b.idCategory = a.idCategory and a.timeStamp > b.timeStamp ORDER BY b.timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY timeStamp DESC]; Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

Im not good at SQL, so dont know how to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only **one** parameter in your `PreparedStatement`, you should not pass **two** parameters into it. Maybe you can change `new Object[] { categoryId, categoryId }` into `new Object[] { categoryId }`.

Comment: That solved the error but gave me another error:  org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 3

Comment: @benskiiii [`queryForObject()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Class%29) expects one row with only one column, your query produces more than one column

Answer (score 0):

changed it to

```
        String SELECT_getWhenValueChanged = "SELECT a.* FROM status AS a WHERE a.idCategory = ? AND a.value = ? AND a.timeStamp > (SELECT b.timeStamp FROM status AS b WHERE b.idCategory = ? and b.value <> ? ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY timeStamp ASC LIMIT 1";
    try {
        Survey surveyTemp = (Survey) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(SELECT_getWhenValueChanged,
                        new Object[] { categoryId, presentSurvey.getValue(), categoryId, presentSurvey.getValue() },
                        new SurveyMapper());
```

And that worked! thanks

Answer (score -1):

//   In Spring DAO Module using On that time these Exception is raised

```
// Correct Code
public StudentRegistrationBean select(int studentId) {

    StudentRegistrationBean queryForObject = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
             "SELECT * FROM STUDENTREGISTRATION WHERE STUDENTID=?", new Object[] { studentId },
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<StudentRegistrationBean>(
                    StudentRegistrationBean.class));
    return queryForObject;

// Wrong Code
public StudentRegistrationBean select(int studentId) {

    StudentRegistrationBean queryForObject = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "SELECT * FROM STUDENTREGISTRATION WHERE STUDENTID=?", new Object[] { studentId },
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<StudentRegistrationBean>(
                    StudentRegistrationBean.class));
    return null;
```

**Conclusion:**  if you are retuning values you might mistake in put "null" type of values... Means Some thing Make Mistake Methods Writing (OR) return null values